# Getting reference to Outlook mailbox root in a macro

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to move items into a specific folder.

I'm able to move the items into a child folder of the inbox using the typical

```
myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("myfolder")
```

I want to move items into an arbitrary folder. This currently works fine;

```
myNameSpace.Folders("Mailbox - Main").Folders("myfolder")
```

But I don't want to hardcode the path. I want to put this macro on a couple of systems and was hoping to avoid writing a unique version for each user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the root of the default store, use the Inbox parent:

```
myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("my‌​folder")
```

Comment: If you want the root of the default store, use the Inbox parent: myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent

Comment: So i can do - namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("myfolder") ??

Comment: Yep, that will give you the folder named "myfolder" on the same level as the Inbox.